# How can I update a column with a value from a list of values for a set of records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I do an update in a table row by row:

```
UPDATE table  
SET col = $value  
WHERE id = $id
```

Now if I update e.g. 10000 records each record gets the `$value` but it does not really matter which `$id` gets which `$value`. The only requirement I have is that all the records I am updating end up with a `$value`.
So how could I convert this update to something like

```
UPDATE table  
SET col ?????? what here from a $value_list???
WHERE id IN ($id_list)
```

I.e. pass the list ids and somehow the values and that range of ids get *a* value

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you've got two comma separated lists of your ids and your values with the same count of items. Then you could do your update with statements like those:

```
-- the list of the ids
SET @ids = '2,4,5,6';
-- the list of the values
SET @vals = '17, 73,55, 12';

UPDATE yourtable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.ids, ',', n.n), ',', -1) id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.vals, ',', n.n), ',', -1) val
    FROM (SELECT @ids as ids, @vals as vals) t 
    CROSS JOIN (
        -- build for up to 1000 separated values
        SELECT 
            1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
           ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
           ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
        ORDER BY n
    ) n
    WHERE n <= (1 + LENGTH(t.ids) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.ids, ',', '')))
) t1
ON
    yourtable.id = t1.id
SET
    yourtable.val = t1.val;
```

**Explanation**

The inner series of UNIONs builds a table with the numbers from 1 to 1000. You should be able to expand this mechanism to your needs:

```
-- build for up to 1000 separated values
SELECT 
    a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + 1 AS n
FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
ORDER BY n
```

We use this numbers to get the items out of our lists with the nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX` call

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.ids, ',', n.n), ',', -1) id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.vals, ',', n.n), ',', -1) val
```

The WHERE clause get the number of items in (ok only one of the two) lists:

```
WHERE n <= (1 + LENGTH(t.ids) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.ids, ',', '')))
```

Because we've got one occurence of the separator less, we add 1 to the difference in length of the list with the separator and the length of the list without all occurrences of the separator.

Then we do the UPDATE with a JOIN operation on the id values in the outer UPDATE statement.

See it working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a47/2).

Believe me: This is much faster than agonizing row-by-row update.

Comment: But I have like 10.000 ids and values at a time. Can I use sql variables like you do with so many values?

Comment: You could reach the [maximum allowed packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)  limit. That mostly depends on the size of your values. The separator of the list may not be contained in those too, if the values are for example strings. If you get near the that limit, you could work with batches of say a 1000 each. So you would drastically limit the number of queries.

Comment: +1.I will need to study this answer carefully a bit to fully understand it.One question. Is this more efficient than use a `CASE id WHEN 1 then val1 etc` and construct this query in the application via string concats?

Comment: You could test this, but with the concatenation of those cases you will reach the max allowed packet size earlier and your statement will be very unwieldy. You could implement both and do a bit of benchmarking.